# Reading a large text file to memory in C++

Tags: c++, file-io, large-files

Is there a way to read a large text file (~60MB) into memory at once (like a compiler flag to increase program memory limit) ? Currently, ofstream's open function throws a segmentation fault while trying to read this file.

```
ifstream fis;
fis.open("my_large_file.txt"); // Segfaults here
```

The file just consists of rows of the form

```
number_1<tabspace>number_2
```

i.e., two numbers separated by a tabspace.

Comment: 60MB isn't a large file ;-)

Comment: when it comes to I/O it is a bit OS dependent, sometimes it is more effective to circumvent the C++ functions and directly access the OS API functions for reading files.

Comment: What compiler?  .open doesn't even read data in, so does this work for ANY file on your machine?  Are you SURE it segfaults on the .open call?  What do you do next with fis?

Comment: I'm using g++. Small text files (~100K) are successfully opened with this call; I have used gdb to ascertain that it indeed segfaults on this call...I need to use fis to load file data into a STL-map.

Answer (score 5):

You have some other problem, because you aren't *reading* the file by just calling `open`. My guess is the file doesn't exist (or doesn't exist in the relative path you think it should exist in).

Comment: I concur with your "some other problem" comment but neither of those should cause a SEGV.

Comment: The path is valid because it pauses for around 20s trying to open the file, then throws a segfault. I'm able to open smaller files in the same directory with this call.

Comment: Actually it can segv if it throws an unhandled exception: "depending on the value set with exceptions an exception may be thrown". And because it waits for 20s, I'm going to further guess it's trying to browse the network for some reason (network mapped drive?)

Comment: If it's a UNIX system, that 20s may be partially spent writing out the core file.